How to create a generic interface that allows nullable get properties in .NET 8 C#
I am trying to create a generic interface to be applied to class objects that have to be auditable: i.e. have the ID of the user that created, modified, or deleted the object, and the DateTime of the event.
The problem is that an object that has not been modified or deleted must have a null value for the corresponding Id and Date values.
My current definition is:
public interface IAuditedEntity<UserIdType>
{
    UserIdType CreatedBy { get; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; }
    UserIdType? ModifiedBy { get; }
    DateTime? DateModified { get; }
    UserIdType? DeletedBy { get; }
    DateTime? DateDeleted { get; }
}

public class AuditedClass : IAuditedEntity<int>
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified {get; protected set; }
    public int? DeletedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; protected set; }
}

In Visual Studio 2022 (latest release), I get an error that the interface is not completely implemented.
I need the generic because in this module the user's Id is an int, but in other modules it could be a string or GUID.

What's the exact error you are getting?

If you are using SQLServer, you might want to take a look at Temporal Tables as a nice solution for auditing like this.

I don't get your auditing style here? Your objects can be only modified never or once?

The problem here is that you're getting confused by the syntax you're using. T1? and T2? aren't the same generic type behind the scenes with different specializations, because for example T1 might be an int (which makes the first type Nullable<int>) and T2 might be string (which makes the second type String, not Nullable<String>).
In other words, the little question mark means different things depending on the type of the object you're attaching it to, and it specifically means nothing (to the CLR) when attached to a reference type.
To get your example to compile, the fix is trivial, simply specify in which of the two cases you fall:
interface IAuditedEntity<UserIdType> where UserIdType: struct

The rest of the code will compile as-is.
The same will work for Guid (it's a value type), but not for string (it's a reference type). A string won't bind to that interface, you'll have to make a different one for reference types to use.

You didn't ask for this so I'll leave it as a comment, but in my opinion you're handling this the wrong way. A much easier approach would be source generation with no inheritance, and auto-mapping if strictly necessary to bridge the gaps.

Blindy: Thanks for the hint, I guess I just missed that detail when I was looking at the operator. Of course, that blew up the whole reason for the generic, because the types that were to be used were int, GUID and string!

Your interface should use type T i.e.
public interface IAuditedEntity<T>
    {
        T CreatedBy { get; }
        DateTime DateCreated { get; }
        T? ModifiedBy { get; }
        DateTime? DateModified { get; }
        T? DeletedBy { get; }
        DateTime? DateDeleted { get; }

    }

Then your actual implementations can be any type of T such as int i.e.
public class AuditedClass : IAuditedEntity<int>{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified {get; protected set; }
    public int DeletedBy { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted { get; protected set; }
}


Renaming a type doesn't change anything about how the code works.

That's pretty much the same code. The generic type parameter don't need to be called T, that's just a standard. UserIdType is just as good identifier as T.
